# how to retrieve dynamic emails with Gmail-api

Tags: email, dynamic, gmail, gmail-api, amp-email

I'm using the gmail api to create a Gmail manager to my application (php). I'm using the documentation provided by google for php and all works correctly except the dynamic emails. I was looking for information about it but I didn't find anything.

I show you some examples of how I see it in my application and how it should be.

Pinteres email:

[image: in my app]

[image: in gmail]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question should have your effort to solve the task. Here you post abstract question which people will likely delete rather answer. Code is good, environment, screenshots, error codes if any. I would recommend you to check SO's [official How to Ask article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

To access AMP Email using GMAIL API, you should probably get the raw email. This can be done by passing the format as `raw`. The details are available in the official documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get).

**Example code will be somewhat like below in javascript:**

```
function getMessage(userId, messageId, callback) {
  var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.get({
    'userId': userId,
    'id': messageId,
    'format' : 'raw'
  });
  request.execute(callback);
}
```

> Note: Please note that the response will be raw base64 data.

If you are unable get it here, then Gmail should probably be stripping off the same from the response for security reasons. AMP Email is considered sensitive.